# SwiftUI: How to change @EnvironmentObject in runtime? / How to pass different NSManagedObjectContext in runtime?

Tags: swiftui, core-data, environment-variables, cloudkit, nsfetchrequest

I have a SwiftUI app using Core Data and CloudKit with the `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer`. I pass the `NSManagedObjectContext` to my views with an environment variable like so:

```
WindowGroup {
    HomePage()
        .environment(\.managedObjectContext, DataManager.instance.context)
}
```

I have a toggle for tuning iCloud sync on and off, which generates the new `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer`, which in turn creates a new context. However, all the fetched data before with the `@FetchRequest` still uses the previous context from the environment object, hence manipulating it is no longer possible and I get errors.

I need to pass the new context to my views, so that `@FetchRequest` would use it instead. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

`NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` is just a wrapper for a core data stack where the first store description is configured for CloudKit. It isn't a good idea to completely replace it, instead you can just add or remove stores and reset the context. You can also have a cloud store and a local store active at the same time and use [assign](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506436-assign) to choose which store to save an object to. Same thing for fetching. This can be achieved with configurations and was demoed in one of the WWDC talks.

If `@FetchRequest` really doesn't update when the context environment value changes then that's a bug and we'll have to submit a feedback request to get it fixed.